# What do you call a balcony above another balcony in a stadium?

Tags: word-request

[image: bal]

What do you call a balcony above another balcony in a stadium? As you can see, there's 2 balconies, or balcony section separated by a LCD panels and I was wondering if these balconies were even called balconies. If they're not called balconies, what are they called and what do you call the upper-most balcony?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really a uniform word to specify a balcony above a balcony. If you look at seating charts of arenas they use various words to differentiate the upper balcony and the lower balcony:

> Lower vs. Upper:
>
> [Mezzanine vs. Upper](https://www.prucenter.com/images/event/seatingbasketball.jpg)
>
> [Lower vs. Upper](https://s1.ticketm.net/tmimages/venue/maps/ch6/85278s.gif)
>
> [Loge vs. Balcony](https://www.cincinnatiarts.org/assets/img/Aronoff-Center-Procter-Gamble-Hall-chart-view.png)
>
> [Section 2 vs. Section 3](https://vucommodores.com/images/2012/7/3/mbbseatinghart7312prices.jpg)

But generally **Upper Level Balcony** and **Lower Level Balcony** are good enough to differentiate, but might not match the specific stadiums *official* name for that section.

In addition other compound words would also work if there are more than two balconies:

**Second Level Balcony**

**Second Tier Balcony**

Answer (score 0):

In British English, the top level balcony in a theatre is called "The gods", I guess because you are so high up it's like you are with the gods.